# Adding a text view before a repeating text view

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-activity, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to build a notepad application. In my layout there are two TextView. First text view only shows a string "Your Saved Entries", where second TextView shows the titles of saved entries. My problem is the First TextView is repeating with all the titles of saved entries. I want the string "Your Saved Entries" will appear for one time and then All the titles of saved entries will be shown. Please help me

[image: Your Saved Entries is repeating with Entry titles]

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingRight="3dp" 
       android:paddingLeft="3dp"
       android:paddingTop="15dp"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       >
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/intro" />


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/postslist" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="8dp"
   android:textSize="20sp" 
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"

   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity file

```
package com.ex.fastnotes;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Notesli extends ListActivity {

     public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
     private ListView conListView;
     private CursorAdapter conAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        conListView=getListView();
        conListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewConListener);

        // map each name to a TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.postslist };

        conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Notesli.this, R.layout.tlist, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
       super.onResume();  
       new GetContacts().execute((Object[]) null);
     } 


    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
       Cursor cursor = conAdapter.getCursor();

       if (cursor != null) 
          cursor.deactivate();

       conAdapter.changeCursor(null);
       super.onStop();
    }    


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
    {
       DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(Notesli.this);

       @Override
       protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
       {
          dbConnector.open();
          return dbConnector.getAllContacts(); 
       } 

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
       {
          conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
          dbConnector.close();
       } 
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.corefile, menu);
       return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
       Intent addContact = new Intent(Notesli.this, Corefile.class);
       startActivity(addContact);
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    OnItemClickListener viewConListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
       {         
          Intent viewCon = new Intent(Notesli.this, ViewNotes.class);
          viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
          startActivity(viewCon);
       }
    };    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your CustomArrayAdapter by extending any Adapter class. From that you have to check using any flag whether it was Saved Entry or not if yes then show your first textview otherwise just empty/hide your textview.

Make custom of For your list item container which contain data in your custom class having one boolean object to identify the current saving entry. When you edit/create new note just flag object value to true before setting this true you must iterate all other list item and set false to all items flag then set the current item flag to true.

Now you have to implement getView() whichever you Adapter extend it. In this method check value by getting list item based on position and get the item flag value if it was true then set your first textview to visible otherwise set to gone for others.